# Query all types of a document field or a specific type with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

So, I need to find documents in the db based on the request query, but if nothing is specified I want to find all the documents, so I made something like this (with mongoose-paginate-v2):

```
    // query params
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const category = req.query.category || '*';
    const type = req.query.type || '*';

    // query posts
    let posts = await Post.paginate({
        postCategory: category,
        postType: type
    }, {
        page: page,
        limit: 10
    });
```

This returns an empty array, probably because the mongodb query doesn't have any sense. But if the category and the type are not specified, is there a way to query for every document?

Answer (score 1):

Default page should be `0` instead of `1`. Create `filter` object only with data that is sent. Change `paginate` to `find`.

```
// query params
const page = parseInt(req.query.page || 0);
let filter = {};
if(req.query.category) filter.postCategory: req.query.category;
if(req.query.type) filter.postType: req.query.type;

// query posts
let posts = await Post.find(filter, { page: page });
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it just returns an empty array of docs

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try it again? It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ?? (nullish coalescing) operator instead of || you can set your req.query.page even to 0.
Your code should look something like this

```
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) ?? 1;
const query = {}
if(req.query.category) {query.category = req.query.category}
if(req.query.type) {query.category = req.query.type}

// query posts
let posts = await Post.paginate(query, {
  page: page,
  limit: 10
});
```